# Django model with editable=False and filter that field in Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have this model:

```
class Values(models.Model):
    ip_given = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    ip_discovered = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    poi = models.ForeignKey(POI, editable=False)
    sensor = models.ForeignKey(Sensor, editable=False)
    value = models.FloatField()

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The fields poi and sensor are editable=False because I set them automatically when creates the object. By other hand, I have this modelAdmin:

```
class ValuesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'ip_given', 'ip_discovered', 'value', 'time', 'poi', 'sensor')
    list_display_links = ('id',)
    list_filter = ('poi', 'sensor', 'time', 'value')
```

The problem is that I can filter by time and also by value, but poi and sensor are not shown in the filter section. I think It is because the editable=False attribute.

There is any way to filter by that fields without delete the editable=False attribute?

Comment: have you tried something as 
`list_filter = ('poi__id', 'sensor__id', 'time', 'value')`
for relational filters as discussed in this manual page for span accross relations
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: That was! @cmidi Please, can you put your comment as response to Mark It as valid? Thanks

Comment: Done. You can accept and edit the answer based on your findings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like

```
list_filter = ('poi__id','sensor__id','time','value')
```

You can use relational filters as discussed in this manual page for span across relation.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin